# Publish to file/ftp from Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, publish

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio for Mac (and actually developing on Mac). In Visual Studio for Windows there is an option to publish to file, ftp etc. only including the files needed in the build version. How do I accomplish the same on Mac?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, been working for a few days now and wanted to stick this on my IIS server and only option is Publish to Azure???

Comment: There's no option that I'm aware of on Visual Studio Community Mac. What I do is use a FTP client (like FileZilla) and then for Azure WebJobs, I just do a dotnet publish -c RELEASE, and I just copy over the assemblies modified (if you make changes to dependencies, it's best to delete everything in the folder and then reupload everything). It's good to use SFTP too by the way.

Comment: Thanks @pqsk :) Sorry for the late answer.

Comment: oh np @Stronghold, I'm hoping that's a good solution for you. It works for me.